# subscript characters in String

Tags: c#, wpf, string, subscript

In my WPF C# project I'm using docX library to create word documents.
With this .NET library I could create String and add inside a docx file as Paragraph. 
My docx needs to have some subscript characters, for example:

Fb (b as subscript)

I know that there are Unicode characters and numbers for subscript, but some chars are not included.
So, how can I add that subscript chars in a C# String?

Comment: Why don't you format (as in text formatting) the subscript text with the appropriate methods? Seems better than using a specific subscript character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a "How to write text as Subscript?" forum post webpage on the old codeplex.com, which is no longer available, you need to create a new `Novacode.Formatting` object. From the linked page:

> You need to create a new formatting and assign the values you want to
> the font.
>
> Dim fotext As New Novacode.Formatting
>
> fotext.Script = Script.subscript
>
> p.InsertText("Text here", False,fotext)
>
> p being the paragraph that you're wanting to insert text into.

In C#, that would be something like this:

```
Novacode.Formatting fotext = new Novacode.Formatting();
fotext.Script = Script.subscript;
p.InsertText("Text here", false, fotext);
```

Comment: Codeplex link to forum is no more available.